# Introduce literal strings in PS command

Tags: debian, ps

I usually lauch this command:

```
ps -p 1 --format "command %c running from %t"
```

But last version in Debian 12, I can't:

```
ps -p 1 --format "command %c running from %t"
error: improper AIX field descriptor

Uso:
 ps [opciones]

 Try 'ps --ayuda <simple|lista|salida|hilos|varios|todo>'
  or 'ps --ayuda <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
```

How can I use literal in --format option of ps, without the use of more complex command line (whitout ps --format ... | awk '{ print ...})

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use literal in --format option of ps, without the use of more complex command line (whitout ps --format ... | awk '{ print ...})

You can't. The only format string permitted is one where the %x format specifiers are separated by zero or more spaces. You could submit a bug report to find out if this is intentional given earlier versions of `ps` permitted your freetext format string.

Credit: https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.user/c/fmOBn7aQo9Q

Comment: I think it's a possible bug in Debian. Strings in --format argument are valid in older versions of Debian and also in recent versions of other distributions (fedora).